# ¿Perderé los inserts que ya había hecho a la tabla si la renombro desde el modelo(código C#)?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, code-first

Estoy trabajando con Entity Framework Code First. Me preguntaba si renombrando una tabla desde el modelo(código C#) Perdería los inserts que ya había hecho en la tabla.

He visto que si renombro la tabla y hago la migración (Con *Add-Migration + "Name"* desde la consola de Paquetes Nuget) el fichero automático que se crea elimina y vuelve a crear las Foreign Keys y quería saber si eso hará que también se elimine el contenido de la tabla (al hacer el *Update-Database* desde la consola de Paquetes Nuget).

¿Pasa lo mismo si elimino una columna de una tabla (es decir, si borro una variable del modelo)?

Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Hace un backup de tu base de datos, siempre, antes de probar cualquier cosa. Y lo probaste?ç

Comment: @gbianchi Sí, he hecho BackUp, pero solo he probado el eliminar una columna, y sí, mantiene el contenido de la tabla. Merci Gonzalo